# Using SBJson with facebook sdk static library

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, sbjson

At the moment when I try to have the SBJson library alongside the facebook-ios-sdk I get

`'duplicate interface definition for class 'SBJsonParser''`

come up.

So I have created a static facebook-ios-sdk library and then I have also got my standard SBJson library in the same project. I get the error.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this? I really need to use that library in my application... as I already have a good few thousand lines of code in this library and need to implement facebook too...

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Got the same problem now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facebook SDK already contains the SBJSON library. That is why you are getting a duplicate definition error. Try removing your SBJSON files and then `#import "SBJSON.h"`, it should get the file from your facebook SDK.

Try: `initWithData:encoding:` NSString method.

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Comment: Ok but I get an error saying "no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'JSONValue'" ?? It happens when I have a data stream (NSDAta)         NSDictionary * dict = [data JSONValue];

Comment: Are you sure you can `JSONValue` data? Taken from SBJSON git hub: `Call [str JSONValue] on any NSString instance to parse its JSON text`. I updated my answer.

Comment: is latest Facebook sdk have this issue? i think now they added prefix "FB" for all SBJson classes used in SDK. Pls refer http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/202230616574138/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301617/application-crash-on-login-in-ios-facebook-sdk-3-0/12315467#12315467